# REGEX: Replacing mutilple character sets in one expression (Vanity numbers) (NOT Java)

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-replace

Is there a pure Regular Expression way to replace multiple sets of characters with one expression?  A classic example is US vanity phone numbers, such as 1-xxx-CALL-SAM, which would convert to 1-xxx-225-5626.  (Don't worry about the dashes! They will be stripped anyway.)  We would like to do this with Oracle's REGEXP_REPLACE capability, which does not have Java's MAP capability, etc., built in.

Thanks!
Dennis

Comment: It looks like you'll need to call `REGEXP_REPLACE` once for each distinct replacement or each "set of characters" to match.

Comment: Regular Expressions don't themselves do calculations, they just search.

Comment: So something like find `[ABC]`, replace `1` for each set as @JohnBollinger says.

Comment: you'd probably be best wrapping all your phone cleaning logic in a single function

Answer (score 1):

Use TRANSLATE
Limited example

```
 Translate(str,'ACLMS','22566')
```

should work for your example. Extend with other characters as required.